# Unexpected output in Tasking?

Tags: task, ada

Why it is not sure for below code that task_1 should execute first then task_2 because task_1  which is in waiting state get  first start message from main? but output is not predictable please help me to understand?

```
 WITH Ada.Text_IO;                  --  Include Text_IO Library
 WITH Ada.Integer_Text_IO;    --  Include Integer Text_IO Library
 PROCEDURE task_demo_02 IS
TASK TYPE intro_task (message1 : Integer) IS  
      ENTRY start;             --  Entry Point Into The Task
  END intro_task;

  TASK BODY intro_task IS       --  Task Body Definition
BEGIN
 ada.text_io.put_line("waitng");
   ACCEPT start;            --  Entry Point Into The Task
   Ada.Text_IO.put ( "Display from Task ");
   Ada.Integer_Text_IO.put (message1,  1);
   Ada.Text_IO.new_line;
   END intro_task;
  Task_1 : intro_task (message1 => 1);--activate
  Task_2 : intro_task (message1 => 2);--activate

   BEGIN
   ada.Text_IO.put_line("main");
   Task_1.start;  --- first task_1 should execute
   Task_2.start;   --- then task_2 isn't it ?
   END task_demo_02;
```

Comment: Give some example(s) of the actual output you are getting. And, *please*, lay your code out properly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
BEGIN
   ada.Text_IO.put_line("main");
   Task_1.start;  --- first task_1 should execute
```

Your comment seems to assume that this will cause `Task_1` to execute, and `Task_1` will finish executing until it's done, and then the main program will go on to `Task_2.start`.

But that's not the case.  `Task_1.start` means that `Task_1` is now ready to execute.  But at this point, there are two tasks ready to execute: `Task_1`, and the *environment task*, which is the task that's running `task_demo_2`.  You can't really tell which task is run first (there are some *dispatching policies* that will specify how tasks get run in a case like this, but in general you can't tell).  That means that `task_demo_02` could keep running, which means `Task_2.start` will happen before `Task_1`continues.  Or it could mean that `Task_1` starts, but that the processor will split time between `Task_1` and `task_demo_02`.  Or, on a multi-processor system, they could both run in parallel.

If you want to write a program where the main program starts `Task_1` and waits for it to finish, the most reliable way is to add another entry:

```
TASK TYPE intro_task (message1 : Integer) IS  
    entry Start;
    entry Finish;
END intro_task;

Task_1.Start;
Task_1.Finish;
```

and then, at the end of `intro_task`, add

```
accept Finish;
```

Comment: thank you a lot when ever i get your reply to my question i get clear picture of my question again thanks a lot .. :-)